# Handling session with Struts 2 and Spring security 3

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security, actioncontext

I am trying to integrate Struts 2 and Spring security 3.
I don't understand how to handle session, with both.Is there a standard way?

I know of struts session built in session handling, ActionContext

eg

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("userIdx","xxxxx");
```

But not how to use spring security along with it.

There are lots of Spring MVC tutorials on using Spring Security 3, 
but not a lot on Struts 2 and Spring Security 3. 
Do you know of any good tutorials? 
Or would I be better using Spring MVC?

Comment: check this out may be will give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886256/how-do-i-get-the-spring-security-sessionregistry

Comment: there is no problem in integrating Struts 2 with Spring Security 3. There is as such no need to move to Spring MVC. I have made application using these two but till now I did not use specifically session. Are you facing any problem with session ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, but just to clarify.

In struts 2 you can have session stored in ActionContext.
And in Spring security 3, in SessionRegistry.

Should I just use SessionRegistry, in Spring Security and ignore session in ActionContext.

Or, if you have experience of using both with session, how did you handle it.

Comment: @kfl The session is the session: all the action context does is wrap up access to the session map.

Comment: @kfl agree with Dave!! Additionally will not suggest to user ActionContext rather user SessionAware